# Firebase database modeling

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

I'm starting out using firebase and even though I've spent 2 days on firebase db and nosql I'm still not sure if I'm on the right track.

I'm working on a fairly simple usecase/dataset:
I have content-items (title, **coordinates**, ...) which can be attributed to subcategories. Subcategories are attributed to categories.

Sound simple? Ok, I created the following:

```
{
  "contentitems": {
    "item1": {
      "title": "i am a content item",
      "coordinates": ""
    },
    "item2": { ... },
    "item3": { ... }
  },

  "subcategories": {
    "sc1": {
      "title": "i am a subcategory",
      "contentitems": {
          "item1" : true,
          "item2" : true
      }
    },
    "sc2": {
      "title": "i am another subcategory",
      "contentitems": {
          "item1" : true,
          "item134" : true
      }
    },
    "sc3": { ... }
  },


  "categories": {
    "c1": {
      "title" : "i am a cateogry,
      "subcategories": {
          "sc1" : true,
          "sc2" : true
      },
    },
    "c2": { ... },
    "c3": { ... }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell this should be fine for the following usecase (in an app):
I click on a category from the categories list and open a list with all related subcategories. When I click on a subcategory I open a list with all related content-items.

**Is this correct? Are there any pitfalls I can't see at the moment? Am I completly off?**

2n part of my question:
How can I achieve a geolocation search with a bounding box? Do I have to create another 'table' called geocoordinates like this:

```
"geocoordinates": {
  "coords" : {
    lat: "45",
    lon: "44"
  }
}
```

How can I get all data within the bounding box?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without more details about how the data is to be used. I like the question and it looks like you are going the right direction. But. Why are the sub-categories sc1, sc2 etc in separate node? Why are the items in a separate node? In Firebase 'the flatter the better' but there needs to be a reason to do so as unnecessaryily denormalizing data can also lead to more complex querying. The use case you provided doesn't lead to the structure you have (it's a great structure by the way!) so maybe more data would help us.

Comment: Ran out of space... Continuing - it appears items are reusable and appear in several subcategories, so that part of the structure works. Are the subcategories a one to many or are they tied to a specific category? How will your queries work? What will you query on?

Comment: Thanks for you input. Yes, subcategories can be tied to multiple categories and items can be tied to mutiple subcategories.
Concerning queries: I need to query a list of:
|+all items+|
|+all items in a subcategory+|
|+all subcategories in a category+|
|+all categories+|
|+all items within a region (bounding box)+|
I don't need a list of all items for a category (at least not as far as i can tell at the moment). What I don't understand is how i could put the subcategories without a node. How would tihs work? Could you please explain.

Comment: I am not advising this, but sub-categories are well, sub. Meaning a child node - category_0/sub_cat_1 and category_0/sub_cat_1. If They are tired directly to a category then they could be placed there. However there are a lot of if, and's and buts: if there are a lot, the should be in their own node; if you need to query on something inside the sub_cat, they should be in their own node. However, if they are a few of them and they are not going to be queried deeply, they could easily live within the category parent.